# Expanding a record with unknown keys in Power Query

Tags: json, database, powerbi, azure-cosmosdb, powerquery

I am working with a nested json file. The issue is that the keys of the nested json are dates and their value is not known beforehand. Therefore I am unable to apply expandRecordColumn method on it.

Each row has a unique refId and looks like this

```
{
     "refId" : "XYZ",
     "snapshotIndexes" : {
               "19-07-2021" : {
                          url: "abc1",
                          value: "123"
                },
                "20-07-2021" : {
                          url: "abc2",
                          value: "567"
                }
       }
}
```

I finally want a table with these columns,

```
refid    |     date     |     url      |    value
XYZ      |  19-7-2021   |     abc1     |      123 

XYZ      |  20-7-2021   |     abc2     |      567

PQR      |  7-5-2021    |     srt      |      999
```

In the new table, refId and date will together make a unique entry.

This is powerBi snapshot
[Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhprJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using Record.ToTable on each row to convert from record to table and then applying ExpandTableColumn

```
  let
        Source = DocumentDB.Contents("sourceurl"),
        Source = Source{[id="dbid"]}[Collections],
        SourceTable= Source{[db_id="dbid",id="PartnerOfferSnapshots"]}[Documents],
        ExpandedDocument = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(SourceTable, "Document", {"refId", "snapshotIndexes"}, {"Document.refId", "Document.snapshotIndexes"}),
        TransformColumns = Table.TransformColumns(ExpandedDocument,{"Document.snapshotIndexes", each Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Record.ToTable(_), "Value", {"url","id","images"}, {"url","id","images"})}),
        ExpandedTable = Table.ExpandTableColumn(TransformColumns, "Document.snapshotIndexes", {"Name","url","id","images"}, {"Document.dates","Document.url","Document.id","Document.images"})
    in
        ExpandedTable
```